# Wine says "fixme:heap:HeapSetInformation" when trying to run command

Tags: linux, wine

`Fedora 21 x64 (LXDE spin)
wine-1.7.30 (Compholio)`

Under Linux Wine I'm trying to execute this command:

```
$ wine "/home/user/.foobar2000/drive_c/Program Files/foobar2000/foobar2000.exe" /runcmd-playing="Tagging/Quick Tagger/Set <Rating> to/[Remove Field]"
```

Problem is that when I execute it I get this error

```
fixme:heap:HeapSetInformation (nil) 1 (nil) 0
```

---

Although i'm able to execute the code, i'm greeted with an error at every login.

This is because I have it in LXDE's lxde-rc.xml config file. It says there is an error at the end of the very file but that's due to this particular syntax, so the error message is irrelevant at this point.

Comment: So now we can focus on the question, where still a few details are completely unknown, such as version of Linux and Wine. It's a Wine error.

Comment: I'd also add there's probably perfectly good tag management software in linux, and chances are there may be a simpler issues. Smells like a [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @JourneymanGeek With a specific application it may be an XY problem. However this affects multiple applications, some with no alternatives. In my case it's HOSAFE's CMS 2.0 (Camera Management Software).

Answer (score 0):

In my experience this has something to do with trying to run a 32-bit program in a 64-bit wineprefix. To fix this, create a 32-bit wine prefix:

```
# This creates one at ~/.wine32 but it can be anywhere you own
# Note that it MUST NOT exist. winecfg MUST create it.
WINEARCH=win32 WINEPREFIX=~/.wine32 winecfg
```

You also need to specify this wineprefix as an environment variable whenever you want to run a 32-bit app. This will set anything in the current shell session to run in the 32-bit wine prefix:

```
export WINEPREFIX=~/.wine32
```

Then run the foobar2k installer then run foobar2k with:

```
wine "/home/user/.wine32/drive_c/Program Files/foobar2000/foobar2000.exe" /runcmd-playing="Tagging/Quick Tagger/Set <Rating> to/[Remove Field]"
```